Plane Wave Expansion contradiction.
According to :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane-wave_expansion
$$e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}} = 4 \pi \sum_{lm} i^l  j_l(kr)  Y_{l}^m ( \mathbf{\hat{k}} )  Y_{l}^{m*} ( \mathbf{\hat{r}} )  $$
A well-known definition for the dirac delta in Physics is:
$$\int d^3 \mathbf{k} e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}} = (2\pi)^3 \delta^3(\mathbf{x})  \qquad \dagger$$
Lets see if we can integrate the plane wave expansion and get a dirac delta. So first we seperate: $d^3 \mathbf{k} = k^2 dk d\Omega ( \mathbf{\hat{k}} ) $. Now we use the following fact:
$$ \int d\Omega ( \mathbf{\hat{k}} ) Y_{l}^m ( \mathbf{\hat{k}} )  =  \sqrt{4\pi } \delta_{l0} \delta_{m0}   $$
and $Y_0^0(\mathbf{\hat{r}}) = 1/\sqrt{4\pi}$.
So let us apply these formulas to perform the integral over the sphere in $\dagger$ first. We get:
$$\int d^3 \mathbf{k} e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}} =  \int k^2 dk *4 \pi \sum_{lm}  \sqrt{4\pi} \delta_{l0}\delta_{m0} i^l  j_l(kr)  Y_{l}^{m*} ( \mathbf{\hat{r}} ) = \int k^2 dk *4\pi \sqrt{4\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}} j_0(kr) = \int k^2 \frac{sin(kr)}{kr}dk $$
using the definition of $j_0(kr) =\frac{sin(kr)}{kr} $. So we are left with
$$ \int d^3 \mathbf{k} e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}} = 4\pi \int k \frac{\sin(kr)}{r} dk $$
Its not clear how the dirac delta comes out from this. Maybe because : we need to use a test function to prove the R.H.S. is indeed a dirac delta function supported at the origin Fine, lets use the simplest test function: $f(\mathbf{x}) = 1$.  By $\dagger$ we should expect then that:
$$ \int d^3 \mathbf{x} *  4\pi \int k \frac{\sin(kr)}{r} dk  = (4\pi)^2 \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty kr \sin(kr) dk dr =   (2\pi)^3$$
which does not appear to be case, which seems like a contradiction... Does anyone know where I went wrong in the calculation?

Actually, you are done already. Indeed, use the spherical coordinates within the complex exponential integral representation of the Dirac delta and you will end up with the very same integral.
